# Пытаюсь настроить Visual Studio C++ для работы libcurl

Tags: c++, http, visual-studio-2010

libcurl.lib я сбросил в папку в visual studio

1>main.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__imp__curl_easy_setopt"
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__imp__curl_easy_perform"
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__imp__curl_easy_strerror"
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__imp__curl_easy_cleanup"
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__imp__curl_easy_init"
1>D:#User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\url2222222\Release\url2222222.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 неразрешенных внешних элементов

```
#pragma comment(lib, "libcurl.lib")
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>


int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я никогда не настраиваю пути. Я всегда копирую файлы в соответствующие папки include и lib. Я скопировал все куда нужно. Возможно lib файл какой то не тот.

Comment: Других ошибок нет? Откуда брался lib-файл?

Comment: Пути настроены правильно, иначе бы компилятор ругался на то что не может найти библиотеку, а здесь видимо нет символов в библиотеке.

Comment: Я сам lib компилировал

Comment: Других ошыбок нет.

Comment: У вас явно не та версия libcurl. Включите детальный вывод в консоль при сборке (Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->MSBuild project build output verbosity). После этого, в окне Output при сборке вы сожете видеть какие библиотеки и объектники фактически компонуются в образ программы.

Comment: Я не смог решить проблему, и решал ее обойти. Использовал библиотеку Poco для своих задач. Вопрос нужно удалить? или написать это сообщение как ответ ? разочаровался в curl, там и еще несколько одинаковых lib компилируется, при разных настройках сборки.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте `#define CURL_STATICLIB`